# Salesforce for Outlook for Mac

Tags: email, salesforce-for-outlook, outlook

One of my team members uses Outlook for Mac and needs to sync to Salesforce. The standard Salesforce for Outlook add-on is for Windows only. Is there a similar app for Mac?

Comment: Are you looking to sync email, or contacts & calendars? are you using exchange server with outlook?

Comment: I'd like to sync emails with the corresponding contact in Salesforce, and events (so yes calendar entry in Outlook).
Just using MS Office Outlook for Mac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Maildrop](http://www.pocketsoap.com/osx/maildrop/). It will work with Outlook 2011 on the Mac.

Answer (score 4):

You can try [Implisit](https://www.implisit.com/). Implisit connects to the backend of your email server and your Salesforce and therefore works on any platform, including Mac and iOS.

**DISCLAIMER:** I work at Implisit

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Riva by Omni Technology Solutions, Inc. http://www.rivacrmintegration.com/ They will sync Salesforce with Outlook for Mac computer system.  They have a basic solution for a very minimal cost.

Answer (score 0):

Take a quick look at [CloudsPlus](http://www.cloudsplus.com) it will synch your contact, calendar tasks as well as email to Salesforce and Exchange server email.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and get onto Exchange sync beta then it doesn't matter what OS or device you are on. Check out summer 15 pre release notes for details

Answer (score 0):

An update on this, we use Cirrus Insights and they just released an Outlook version.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to let you know about our NEW Connector for Outlook and Salesforce.com. Unlike Salesforce it it is NOT going to be discontinued and it does NOT require IE11 or Exchange.It works in Windows and Mac and in any browser and even on mobile.

The new Connector lets you see a 360 degree view of Salesforce from your inbox. It also lets you add emails from your inbox directly to Salesforce as well as create leads from email. It even provides links to your contacts to social media sites inside outlook.

The Connector for Outlook is HERE if you want to try it.   If you can't install it with that link then open outlook and click on Get Add-Ins on the upper right and search for "Salesforce Connector".
Select and install the Salesforce Connector.

Then we reccomend you watch THIS VIDEO on how it works.

Outlook Integration Details

- Provides a 360-degree view of CRM information from Your Inbox
- File a message in iCRM from Outlook
- Automatically associates emails to a contact or lead
- View, create and edit accounts, contacts, leads, opportunities, cases and more from Gmail
- Reply or Compose messages using email templates (even on Mobile)
- Optionally automatically copy emails and attachments to iCRM
- Create rules for which emails get automatically synchronized
- View and dial numbers on your mobile phone using details from iCRM

Outlook Calendar Integration Details

- Automatically synchronize calendar items from Outlook to iCRM
- Automatically links calendar items with CRM Contacts or Leads
- Create rules for which calendar items get synchronized (coming soon)

Disclosure - I work for iEnterprises.